# Using && in a return statement

Tags: c++, return

I am looking at an example of a function that shows if two binary search trees are isomorphic (has the same shape). In the example it returns two statements. I am having a hard time understanding what that means.

```
bool isomorphic(struct treenode *treeone, struct treenode *treetwo)  
{  
    if (!treeone && !treetwo)  
        return true;    
    if((!treeone && treetwo) || (treeone && !treetwo))  
        return false;  

    return (isomorphic(treeone->left, treetwo->left)  
        && isomorphic(treeone->right, treetwo->right));  
}
```

The part I am having trouble with is the last return statement.

The above code came from here: http://tech-queries.blogspot.com/2010/04/isomorphic-trees.html

Comment: It's not clear what makes you think it 'returns two statements'. It appears to be a simple piece of code with three possible execution paths. Maybe the incorrect indenting is confusing you?

Comment: @Chantola _"Just no! Stop coding! There's no hope! "_ That's certainly not the right way to react! Even, if this is a poor question, there's no reason for bullying or step ad hominem. Stay with a professional tone on this site! _(I have flagged your comment as rude/offensive, take care in future not to receive a ban)_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least IMO, the first set of statements:

```
if (!treeone && !treetwo)  
    return true;    
if((!treeone && treetwo) || (treeone && !treetwo))  
    return false;
```

...are really more confusing than they need to be, so I'd start by simplifying them a bit. This is basically checking whether we've reached a leaf node in one or both trees. If the trees are the same "shape", we should reach leaf nodes in both at the same times. So, that means if either one is a null pointer, then (from what we can see at this point) they're same shape if and only if *both* are null pointers.

Note, though, that as soon as we reach a null pointer in *either* tree, we've traversed far enough--we don't need to recurse any further. Either they're both null pointers (so we return true) or one of them is a null pointer and the other isn't (in which case we return false).

We could make that logic a little more apparent though. I think I'd write it something like this:

```
if ((treeone == nullptr) || (treetwo == nullptr))
    return treeone == treetwo;
```

If execution proceeds past that point, neither pointer we received was a null pointer. In this case,  the trees are the same shapes if and only if both their sub-trees are the same shapes. That *could* be written something like this:

```
if (!isomorphic(treeone->left, treetwo->left))
    return false;

if (!isomorphic(treeone->right, treetwo->right))
    return false

return true;
```

However, we're returning `true` if and only if both the sub-statements return true--that is, if statement one is true *and* statement two is true. We can abbreviate that into a logical `and` like this:

```
return isomorphic(treeone->left, treetwo->left) 
   and isomorphic(treeone->right, treetwo->right));
```

Traditionally, however, C and C++ have used `&&` for a logical-and, which gets us back to the syntax as you originally found it.

With current C compilers, however, this code should compile (using `and` instead of `&&`) if you `#include <iso646.h>`. In current C++, you don't even have to do that (though you *may* have to use some special command line switches--for example, VC++ requires `/Za`).

Comment: Thank you so much. I had never it seen it used in that way and my professor is really good with answering questions. But she answers them in the form of another question so I asked her about them and then she responded with "Well isn't that a simple comparison of two unknown values that might be of two different data types" 

Anyways thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The first if statement checks if both nodes passed to the function is NULL. (If both are NULL its isomorphic so returns true).

The second if statement checks if one of the nodes passed to the function is NULL. (In this case apparently they are not isomorphic so return false.)

At this point the function knows that both nodes passed to the function are not NULL.
This means that the first 2 nodes passed to the function are valid (means isomorphic)

But what you want to know is if the entire tree structure is isomorphic. So here the last return statement does the magic.

The last return statement is 2 recursive calls to the function itself.
The first recursive call checks if the nodes in left side are the isomorphic. And the second one is for right side.

This recursive call checks all the nodes in the tree by walking through the nodes.

My recommendation is to write a tree in a notebook and execute the code step by step and see what happens.